# i want to update job along with '_1','_2','_3'... how can i?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

This is the table EMP

```
select * from emp

--------------------
     EMPNO  JOB      
---------- ---------
      7698 MANAGER  
      7782 MANAGER  
      7499 SALESMAN 
      7521 SALESMAN 
      7654 SALESMAN
```

and i want it like

```
---------------------
     EMPNO JOB      
---------- ---------
      7698 MANAGER_1  
      7782 MANAGER_2  
      7499 SALESMAN_3 
      7521 SALESMAN_4 
      7654 SALESMAN_5 
      .... ..........
      .... ..........
```

Comment: Oracle has a [rank](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/rank.php) operator

Comment: how can i update it please explain @hiFi

Comment: On what basis do you want to increment those number suffixes? Please explain it clearly. Also, let us know your attempt.

Comment: @Kaushik the following vaibhab's code is working as per my criteria.. thank u

Comment: It's good that it worked for you, but you should edit your question and show the  expected output correctly to avoid confusion. Also,It is recommended that  you compare the performance of all answers(especially Matthew's )  if you have some time  and use the one which is most efficient for your data set.

Comment: actually i dont know exactly how will edit and not much more about stackoverflow so.. dont mind.. and thank you  @Kaushik Nayak.

Answer (score 1):

```
update emp a set JOB=(select JOB from (select JOB||'_'||rank() over (order by EMPNO  ) JOB,EMPNO  from emp )b where a.EMPNO =b.EMPNO )
where exists (select 1 from emp b where a.EMPNO=b.EMPNO)
```

will give _1,_2,_3,_4 so on order by empno

```
update emp a set JOB=(select JOB from (select JOB||'_'||rank() over (partition by JOB order by EMPNO  ) JOB,EMPNO  from emp )b where a.EMPNO =b.EMPNO )
where exists (select 1 from emp b where a.EMPNO=b.EMPNO)
```

will give _1,_2,_3,_4 so on job wise

Comment: its says ORA-12899: value too large for column "TKM"."EMP"."JOB" (actual: 10, maximum: 9)

Comment: @auro please check your table for datatype and size of field job

Comment: This will not generate values 3,4,5 for the salesmen. It will start over from 1

Comment: @KaushikNayak yes you are right,sorry i forgot to remove partition by,my mistake

Comment: Unfortunately that too doesn't work. See this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/32b55/1  simply using `order by empno` would have  worked if op's data had empno's sorted based on their job, but it isn't. It is not possible to say what's the logic for ordering, unless the OP clarifies it.

Comment: @KaushikNayak so now need  to ask  to auro if it job field has more descr,which ordering req? what is logic behind the numbering

Comment: Well apparently yes and I'm afraid, it appears from the past experiences he/she has disappeared and may never come back :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177879/discussion-between-vaibhav-and-kaushik-nayak).

Answer (score 1):

A `MERGE` will be *way* more efficient than that update.

```
MERGE INTO emp t
USING ( SELECT empno, job || '_' || dense_rank() over ( order by empno ) new_job FROM emp)  u
ON ( t.empno = u.empno )
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET t.job = u.new_job;
```

Comment: But, it still doesn't give the desired output of OP.

Comment: Thanks.  I did not notice that the sequence was across jobs.  I removed the `PARTITION BY` from my answer.  I know the OP's results are not sorted by `empno`.  I am assuming that was a mistake in his post.  The point of my answer is that `MERGE` is much more efficient than the `UPDATE` approach posted by Vaibhav.

Answer (score 0):

it will do :

```
select empno,ename||'_'||rownum from emp;
```

Comment: it is for only retrieve the data. bt i want to update like this